# Calculate Margin in PHP

Tags: php

I hope you can help me on this. I want to have a margin between two numbers no matter if positive or negative. In this case, below I want the result from `$a`or `$b` to be `2`. Of course, I can use some `if else`, but I am sure there is a better and more elegant way to do this in PHP?

It also sounds like Google could show me the correct way within seconds, but I have not found anything useful.

Please help. Thanks very much!

```
$a = 1 - 3;
$b = 3 - 1;

if $a<0{
$result = $a*-1;
}else{
$result = $a;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the absolute value method: [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)

```
$result = abs($a); // $result will be 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `abs(Number)`, i.e. `abs($a)`. [Refer to the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the absolute value, try PHP's builtin `abs` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php